# Effective way to write text file c++

Tags: c++

I am trying to write large text files with minimum consumption of time. First of all i have to initialize a file with empty space. My approach is to make a char array of say 250bytes and then copying it into file. I think this isn't much effective way. Any better idea?

```
char buff[250];
ofstream ofile;
ofile.open("abc.txt");
for(long int i=0;i<20970;i++)
{
  ofile<<buffer;
  ofile<<endl;
 }
```

Comment: You trying copy a line to a file about 21000 times ?

Comment: Yes, inorder to initailze it with empty spaces.

Comment: This sounds like it might be an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).  What is it you are actually trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can seek to the end of the file and write a single character:

```
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc,char** argv) {
    ofstream o("file") ;
    o.seekp(100 * 1024 * 1024);
    o << '\0';

    return 0;
}
```

This is only effective if you know in advance the size of the resulting file.

Answer (score 1):

In Windows, you can create a file of given size, using [SetEndOfFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365531%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). In Linux it is [ftruncate](http://linux.die.net/man/2/ftruncate).

Also make sure to optimize your buffer size when writing. The optimal buffer size depends on system internals, such as page size. But in most cases (if it is not an embedded system), 4-128kb is a good size.