# how to print consloe output into some .txt file in c

Tags: c

```
Min Profile Cycles  [215914]
Max Profile Cycles  [934625]
Max Profile         [23]
Max Profile Count   [4]
```

How to print all these console output into some .txt file in c so that whenever i will call that function it will print in txt file instead of printing in console.

Comment: do not use `stdout` but f.e. `stderr` and redirect the error-chanel to the textfile

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11573974/write-to-txt-file

Comment: possible duplicate of [Effective way to write text file c++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20165219/effective-way-to-write-text-file-c)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One easy way would be to write something like this in your shell :

```
$./a.out > hello.txt
```

Answer (score 3):

as your tag is C, you can fopen() in append-mode a file and instead of using printf() you use fprintf() (and fwrite() and similar) with this filehandle.

Comment: Basically in my case prinf is disabled due to memory constraint in that case how to print the valyes.